# Java Matcher matches() method to match the entire region against the pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have a pattern `(\{!(.*?)\})+` that can be used to validate an expression of format `{!someExpression}` one or more number of times.

I am performing

`Pattern.compile("(\\{!(.*?)\\})+").matcher("{!expression1} {!expression2}").matches()` to match the entire region against the pattern.

There is a space between expression1 and expression2.

Expected -> `false`
Actual -> `true`

I tried both greedy and lazy quantifiers but not able to figure out the catch here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it matches. Your regexp says so. `matches()` matches the whole string, so you're doing exactly what you are asking. The point is, *that regex matches the **whole** string*. Try it in any regex tool.

Specifically, `(.*?)` will happily match `expression1} {!expression2`. Why shouldn't it? You said 'non-greedy' which doesn't do anything unless we're talking about subgroup matching; non-greediness cannot change what is being matched, it only affects, *if* it matches, how the groups are divided out. Non-greedy does not mean 'magically do what I want you to', however useful that might seem to be. `.` will match `}` just as well as `x`.

As a general rule if you're using non-greediness you're doing it wrong. It's not a universal rule; if you really know what you're doing (mostly: That you're modifying how backrefs / group matches / find() ends up spacing it out), it's fine. If you're tossing non-greediness in there as you write your regexp that's usually a sign you misunderstand what you're actually writing down.

Presumably, your intent with the non-greedy operator here is that you do not want it to also consume the `}` that 'ends' the `{!expr}` block.

In which case, just ask for that then: "Consume everything that isn't a }":

```
Pattern.compile("(\\{!([^}]*)\\})+").matcher("{!expression1} {!expression2}").matches()
```

works great.

If your intent is instead that expressions can also contain `{}` symbols and that this is a much more convoluted grammar system then your question cannot be answered without a full breakdown of what the grammarsystem entails. Note that many grammars are not 'regular' (that's a specific term that refers to a subset of all imaginable grammars), then it **cannot** be parsed out with a regular expression. That's what the 'regular' in regular expression refers to: A class of grammars. regexes can be used meaningfully on anything that fits a regular grammar. They are useless for anything that isn't, even if it seems like it could work. Thus, if there is a sizable grammar behind this `{expr}` syntax, it's possible you need an actual full parser for it.

As a simple example, java the language is not regular and therefore cannot meaningfully be parsed with regexes (that is: Whatever aim your regex has, I can write a valid java file that the compiler understands which your regex won't).

Comment: Omg !! that super explanation !! I do not know what can I do to award this as the best detailed answer . Hail you !